# Adding a particular checkbox at the end

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

```
@foreach (Vehicle v in veh)
{
  <input type="checkbox" name="VehicleId" value="@v.VehicleId" id="@v.VehicleId" />
  <span for="@v.VehicleId">@v.Name</span><br />
}
```

Diplays a list of vehicle

- Audi
- BMW
- Honda
- Other
- Toyota

I want to sort the "other" checkbox at the end. Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: `span` don't you mean `label` ? Also just remove other from your vehicles and add it after the loop

Comment: One line of code - `veh= veh.OrderByDescending(v => v != "Other").ThenBy(v => v);` but it belongs in the controller, not the view.

Comment: @StephenMuecke It worked. Thanks for optimizing the code. You are awesome

Comment: @StephenMuecke  Diplays a list of vehicle

Audi
BMW
Honda
Other
Accura
Hyundai
Toyota

is it possible i can sort the first 3 in alphabetical order before the other and following with the rest in alphabetical and other at the very end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `c#` code you can move the `"Other"` element to the end of the list way

```
@{
   var veh = ViewBag.Vehicles.Tolist(); 
   veh = veh.OrderBy(v => v.Name);
   var oldIndex = veh.FindIndex(v => v.Name == "Other");
   var item = veh[oldIndex];
   veh.RemoveItem(oldIndex);
   veh.Add(item);
} 

@foreach (Vehicle v in veh) {
      <input type="checkbox" name="VehicleId" value="@v.VehicleId"   id="@v.VehicleId" />
      <span for="@v.VehicleId">@v.Name</span><br /> 
}
```

Comment: @{var veh = (IEnumerable<Vehicle>)ViewBag.Vehicles; veh = veh.OrderBy(v => v.Name);}
    @foreach (Vehicle v in veh)
{
  <input type="checkbox" name="VehicleId" value="@v.VehicleId" id="@v.VehicleId" />
  <span for="@v.VehicleId">@v.Name</span><br />
}

Where can i make the changes

Comment: @NickB You can take a look at the updated code, You just need to convert the IEnumerable to a list.

Comment: findindex, removeItem, add missing directory or assembly reference

Answer (score 0):

While I don't have experience with ASP.net directly, I've done something similar in Rails. You probably want something like this:

```
def my_sort_funct(v1, v2)
 if v1 == 'other'
   return v2
 elsif v2 == 'other'
   return v1
 else
   return v1 > v2
 end
end
```

And then

```
@vehicals.sort(|a, b| my_sort_funct(a, b)).each do |veh|
  puts veh
end
```